# Which method should I use in writing?

Tags: writing-style

When I am writing, should I let my thoughts flow naturally on the paper, or should I meticulously think them through and form full sentences out of them before putting them to paper? I'm really not sure which one I should use since I have a writing test tmrw and im panicking intensly. When I write naturally, I don't even think about the idea  am writing about, I just start writing from the first word that comes to mind even if it doesn't relate then i connect it into the main idea.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the usage of English. It is a request for writing advice.

Comment: You should do both.  That's the tricky part about writing.

Comment: Without wishing to be rude, it is fairly obvious to me that, when writing your question, you just "let [your] thoughts flow naturally on the paper" *without* "think[ing] them through and form[ing] full sentences out of them before putting them to paper."  This made your question much longer than it need be; makes it more apparent that you're "panicking intensly"; and makes it harder for someone else to read and thake in.  So, I tgink I have answered your question for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use the scrap paper, which is often available during such tests, to write down my thoughts like you described, in a natural manner. Then after I finished a paragraph I start reorganising my sentences if needed and write it down on the answer sheet.

My method is not said to work for you as well, it works for me and many others. You can give it a try, but you'll have to figure out by yourself what works best for you personally.

Lastly there is no need to panic, based on how you wrote your question I'm sure you'll do just fine.

Comment: Writing is like life, you have to think with someone else's head or its relevance is lost.